# Javascript: Element Width Based On Negative Values - From Lesser to Larger

Tags: javascript, css

I have an array as :

```
let arrVals = [{img:'imgOne.jpg', num:-99},
     {img:'imgOne.jpg', num:-500}, 
     {img:'imgTwo.jpg', num:-20}, 
     {img:'imgThree.jpg', num:-33},
     {img:'imgFour.jpg', num:-44}
]
```

Now I loop through this and programmatically generate images from the array of objects inside:

```
<div id="imgContainer">

</div>

for (let i = 0; i < arrVals.length; i++) {
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.src = arrVals[i].img;
 img.style.width = `${arrVals[i].num}px`;
 // appendChild to imgContainer
}
```

I am using the negative values from the objects property, arrVals[i].num but I cannot just convert these to positive numbers and use them as a width value. I am trying to get positive numbers with the largest positive number corresponding to - say - (-30) and smallest - say - corresponding to (-55)

I need to use these values to apply styling width on their corresponding elements. I cannot just convert these values to positive numbers and use them as the one that is supposed to be the smallest (-500 in this example) in terms of width would have the largest width. The above array should corresponds to this results:

CSS Width from smallest to largest based on the array values:

```
> -500 should corresponds to the smallest width
> -99 width is larger than the width given to -500
> -44 width is larger than the width given to -99
> -33 width is larger than the width given to -44
> -20 should have the largest width given its value in the array
```

Any insights on how to achieve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not clear on what widths these should ultimately be converted info. I also don't see a code attempt here.

Comment: two arrays, one is widths in descending order, one with the negative values. Sort Array#2 in ascending and use the index to find the widths. An attempt would make much clearer on what you are trying to do though

Comment: @ggorlen the CSS width. I get these values from an array of objects. I loop through it and grab the value that will be img.style.width as in  img.style.width = `${obj[i].nukber}px`; I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Right, but what values are they supposed to have? What does the "smallest width" entail exactly? I.e. 42, 520, 0? (for all numbers in the output array). What should each `obj[i].nukber` be?

Comment: @ggorlen I updated my question with more details. I hope that helps explain it better.

Comment: @Ggorlen I am also trying to avoid hard coding an array with corresponding values and use it as I would need to be done programmatically based on whatever random values I get in the object property num.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, but if you just make -500 width 1, -99 width 2, -44 width 3, -33 width 4 and -20 width 5, it seems you'll fulfill your stated properties. But that makes no sense, yet I have no idea what widths they _should_ be. Can you write something like: "I want the widths to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`" but replace those with the numbers you actually want, then explain how they got to be those widths? Thanks. Without this info, I can't offer any sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let arrVals = [{ img: 'imgOne.jpg', num: -99 },
    { img: 'imgOne.jpg', num: -500 },
    { img: 'imgTwo.jpg', num: -20 },
    { img: 'imgThree.jpg', num: -33 },
    { img: 'imgFour.jpg', num: -44 }
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrVals.length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        document.getElementById('imgContainer').appendChild(img);  
        img.src = arrVals[i].img;
        img.style.width = `${Math.abs(arrVals[i].num)}px`;
    }
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgQHS.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).